# Why can't I find « booste » in the Collins Dictionary ?

Tags: demande-de-mot

I was reading news titled « [Facebook booste son moteur de recherche pour mieux concurrencer Google](http://www.01net.com/actualites/facebook-booste-son-moteur-de-recherche-pour-mieux-concurrencer-google-924460.html) » but couldn't find the word « booste » in [Collins Dictionary](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/spellcheck/french-english?q=booste). Why is this?

Comment: J’ajouterais bêtement que l’on y trouve «buste» qui phonétiquement n’est pas loin pour nous stimuler et monter le moral. Et puis aux même fins il y a «bustier» qui n’est pas un verbe, mais même sans en avoir l’air ni connexion visible, ça tient bien tout de même !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Collins Dictionaries Online* doesn't have it (it has [*booster*](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english-french/booster), the English substantive; *la fusée de lancement*). It's a [fashionable](http://academie-francaise.fr/dire-ne-pas-dire/recherche?titre=boost&rubrique=&date=&form_build_id=form-yO8xMTd81_7CC9oxIhuA8i8471x8nFSq8E5cVxVcSuc&form_id=academie_blog_search_form&op=Rechercher) loanword from the English language but it is [poorly compatible](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?T1=booster&T3.x=0&T3.y=0) with French in terms of spelling and phonetics. Alternate word choices from the *BDL* :

> gonfler, augmenter, stimuler, encourager, accroître, développer,
>   renforcer, relancer, animer, hausser, dynamiser, doper (langue
>   familière), donner du tonus, donner (ou redonner) de l’élan, donner un
>   coup de fouet, donner un coup de pouce, remonter le moral, faire du
>   battage, promouvoir, valoriser, faire la promotion, faire monter.

And from the *Académie française*:

> Stimuler, régénérer, relancer, augmenter, accélérer, développer, faire
>   croître.

Comment: My Grand Robert & Collins has it: booster (2)
[+ économie, ventes] ▶ to boost
[+ moteur] ▶ to soup up

Comment: Thanks.  Now I know to look up Académie française and the BDL.

Comment: You're welcome. As you can see, sources vary; the more the merrier. Btw. see also [_Larousse_](http://larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais) and [_TLFi_](http://www.cnrtl.fr/lexicographie/#), the latter one also giving you access to many versions of the _Académie_ dictionary per se. But usage may vary. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Because it's a conjugated verb. You need to look up the [infinitive](https://www.lawlessfrench.com/grammar/infinitive/): *booster*, for which *Grand Robert & Collins* offers

> *booster* (2)
>
> [+ économie, ventes] ▶ to boost
>
> [+ moteur] ▶ to soup up

Comment: No, that's not the reason.  The dictionary does recognize conjugated verb forms.  Even the infinitive booster can't be found in Collins.